# VSCode error in search panel when using lookaround regex with unicode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I can't search using regex lookaround with unicode characters in VSCode search panel. As a simple example, consider this:

```
^(?=[\u0600-\u06FF]).+$
```

VSCode shows the following error:

> Regex parse error: character code point value in \x{} or \o{} is too large

I think the error is irrelevant and maybe some bug causes this behavior.

What do you think about that?

Comment: Why do you use a lookahead in the first place? Try `^[\u0600-\u06FF].*$`. What are you looking for?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is the simplest example to domostrate the problem. The real regex is not that simple.

Comment: So, please add it to the question, and explain what it should match and what not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This regex does not do anything useful and just is an example. I'm looking for the reason of the specified error, and I think it shoudn't have error.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I confirm that the question was of low quality. I editted that and tried to be more specific.

Comment: From what I learnt, the pattern is handled by a "customized" PCRE2 regex library once it has lookarounds in it, and there is some issue - probably it is a bug, but might be by design - when the Unicode code points used in the pattern are ["not compatible with the 8-bit library, or which give different output in 16-bit or 32-bit mode."](https://github.com/esy-packages/esy-pcre2/blob/master/testdata/testoutput11-16). I bet there is some problem with how VSCode developers implemented PCRE2 library, so probably it should be logged as a bug.